# golang interface that depends on interface

Tags: go, interface

I am not sure if these should be two separate questions or one, but it seems to me as one question of two parts - How go interfaces are supposed to be used? I have this two struggles:

The methods of the interfaces are globally scoped: If I have interface A and interface B that both implement the same method Foo, but with different arguments or return types I am unable to implement both at the same time from the same type. For example, I have GetBytes() method in one interface having return type []byte and in another ([]byte, error) How I should overcome this issue?

Another issue I have is when I try to define interface say interface A that has a method that returns interface B that is defined in the same layer. Now if I want to create an object that implements A, if I return struct that implements B go is not smart enough to deduce that this method implements the method in A and it forces me to create dependency on B. This seems to completely defeat the point of the way interfaces work in go at first place. How can I avoid this issue?

for example, if I have:

```
type B interface {
    Bar()
}

type A interface {
    Foo() B
}
```

for the following structs :

```
type b_impl struct{}

func (b b_impl) Bar() {}

type a_impl struct{}
```

A foo method

```
func (a a_impl) Foo() b_impl {}
```

does not satisfy the interface A and I need to make it:

```
func (a a_impl) Foo() B {}
```

which makes a dependency to the package where B is declared.

Comment: "How I should overcome this issue?" You can't, since Go doesn't support method overloading. See https://golang.org/doc/faq#overloading. I don't understand your second question well enough to try to answer. Maybe providing a code example would help.

Comment: thanks @smarx - I edited the question with more details for the second part

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do about your second issue either.

Comment: For your second "problem": Were _is_ the problem?  If method Foo returns a Barer it returns a Barer and not a b_impl.

Comment: @Volker Classic programming languages recognize two approaches for specifying protocols between software modules (interfaces vs generics). The interfaces are usually declared from the lower level and are enforced on the upper layers. Generics defined explicitly or implicitly expectations and everything that matches these expectations is good. The golang interfaces act more as generics than typical interfaces. These though is true only when my interface depends on standard (lower level) types where my consumer also depends on. As soon as I need to declare my own type this is no longer true.

Comment: @gsf, I've read your last comment over and over, and I can't make out what you're trying to say. Interfaces are a type that only define a method set, but they are still just a type. If you declare `B` in one package, and reference `B` in another, then of course you need to import B's package. Why is this a problem? The `io` package is frequently imported only to make use of `io.Reader` and `io.Writer`.

Comment: @JimB If I have a protocol that is complex enough to require more than one interface to be specified the whole go paradigm of "late binding" is impossible to use - forcing explicit dependency to my library. Workarounds of this are obviously possible, but ... how is this not a problem?

Answer (score 2):

1st question:
In go you need to make different function names, when you want to do different tasks. Let's look into the standard library at the strconv package how things are solved there: https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#pkg-index

Look to the different declaration of the append function there. There are functions for every different type.

So if you expect a FooInt funtion your interface should be also a FooInter, ...

2nd question:As a small example. You don't need to import the whole io package, when you want to use the io.Writer interface. It is totaly ok to copy the Writer declaration into your own package. If you do that correct, every io.Writer implementation will automatically implement your own Writer interface.

After reading the other comments maybe you have a different situation:

Let's say there is a package a and b with the interface a.A and b.B. If there is the situation that:

```
type A interface{
  Foo() b.B
}
```

and you have to write an implementation for a.A, then you need to import package b. But that makes your binaries not bigger, because you will always need to import package a, which depends on b.

Comment: nope, not theoretical at all. These are two issues that I actually have.

I "need" to change is good suggestion, but since I am not the owner of all I depend on - "I" cannot change it.

For the second question the io.Writer example has nothing to do with my case. Almost every interface that is not obviously trivial as io.Writer requires several interfaces. Since I am not writing standard libraries where dependencies are obtained implicitly - the issue is very real.

Comment: Sorry if that sound a little bit to hard. This should be not the intention, English is not my first language. But when you have existing code it would help to know a little bit more about the existing structure and what parts you need to implement. And I know that your problem is not the io.Writer that was just an example. After reading all the additional comments I understand your problem. If your external package a uses the external Interface b.B there is no other way to solve this then importing package b.

Comment: I have a protocol that includes several interfaces - exactly as explained. A returns B. they both belong to the same package. Now because of that, it is impossible for me to create an implementation of these interfaces without a direct dependency on this package. This will be possible if I do not have that - that's the problem.

Comment: @gsf: I understand what you mean, but then it is not really a Go thing. If the package you have to use is not idiomatic Go code or really bad Go code, maybe it is not a good idea to use it or to search for alternative solutions. I know that this is not allways possible in that case maybe a kind of adapter could work. On this way you can write good Go code in your package and the bad code inside your adapter package. Your adapter would depend on package a and b but inside there you should define interfaces which you can implement inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

For implementing an interface, you need to have exactly the same method name and **signature**. Means the signature must be with the same **types**.

As much as it seems weird, these two don't have the same signature:

```golang
Foo() B
```

```golang
Foo() b_impl {}
```

It doesn't matter that `b_impl` implements `B`.

To overcome the need to import the package `B` is declared in, you can use anonymous type. This way the compiler won't require a specific type for the method signature.

```golang
type A interface {
    Foo() interface{Bar()}
}
```

Which also can be written as embedding `B`:

```golang
type A interface {
    Foo() interface{B}
}
```

Still, `a_impl` must have same signature, so it also needs to return an anonymous interface. You can also declare the same `B` interface in the package of `a_impl`, and embed it in an anonymous interface.

```golang
package impl

type B interface {
    Bar()
}

type b_impl struct{}

func (b b_impl) Bar() {}

type a_impl struct{}

func (a a_impl) Foo() interface{B} {
    return b_impl{}
}
```

I don't know if it's a bad practice or not, probably there are cases which redesign is required instead of doing this.